# How to enumerate from the middle of tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, enumerate

By default, enumerate() starts counting at 0 but if you give it a second integer argument, it'll start from that number instead but how can we enumerate from a particular value of count and elem. for example, we want to pass count as '2' and elem as 'bar'. both values have to pass to enumerate function.

```
elements = ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
for count, elem in enumerate(elements):
    print (count, elem)
```

Comment: @Georgy, I don't actually think that's a good target. The questions are subtly different, there's no need for `iter` here for an input list / tuple, and `str.join` is not applicable.

Answer (score 9):

You can iterate a [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) of your data and start the enumeration at a specific integer:

```
start_at = 1
elements = ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
for count, elem in enumerate(elements[start_at:], start_at):
    print (count, elem)
```

Output:

```
1 bar
2 baz
```

Documentation:

- [enumerate(iterable, start=0)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) (specify whatever for `start` to start numbering the 0th element of `iterable` with that number onwards)

---

Edit:

If you are working with non-sliceable iterators you have to work around it:

```
start_at = 3   # first one included (0 based)
stop_at = 5    # last one (not included)

elements = ('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'wuzz', 'fizz', 'fizzbuzz', 'wuzzfizzbuzz', 'foobarfuzzbizzwuzz')

# skip first few
it = iter(elements)
for _ in range(start_at):
    print("skipping: ", next(it))      # dont print, simply: next(it)

# enumerate the ones you want
i = start_at
for _ in range(stop_at-start_at):
    print(i,next(it))                 # you might need a try: except StopIteration:
    i+=1
```

to get:

```
skipping:  foo
skipping:  bar
skipping:  baz
3 wuzz
4 fizz
5 fizzbuzz
```

Comment: Thankyou for you reply, I have a for loop like this`for batch_id, batch_data in tqdm(enumerate(train_iter)):` , I want to iterate over a particular value of batch_id and batch_data. Can you please suggest me some solution for this please? where batch_id and batch_data i am getting from previous saved values.

Comment: @aryan is the train_iter an iterable? try consuming the first few outside of your loop:  `for _ in range(5): next(train_iter)` to skip first 5 ...

Comment: It is actually dataloader from pytorch and I am trying to start training iterations from previously saved values.

Comment: @aryan see edit - no idea about your dataloader but this works for iterators

Comment: Actually in my case, I just want to give a particular value to batch_id and batch_data, so that enumerate will start from there. where batch_id is int and batch_data is a list.

Answer (score 1):

the itertools module is where you should look when you want to iterate in a non standard way

in this case use [islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

to get the start index, use the `.index` function of the container(or hardcode it to 1 if you want to iterate from the second position regardless of the contents), the end index is the `len` of the container

```
for count, elem in enumerate(itertools.islice(elements, elements.index('bar'), len(elements))
    print(count, elem)
```